# Google Drive API Random 401 Errors

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a service which integrates into the Google Drive API.  On a seemingly random basis I will get 401 responses from requests, and attempting to repeat the request will yield the same response (up to 5 times, at which point we give up the attempt).

Previous and subsequent requests for the same user, using the same authorization headers will be successful.  Indications seem to be that there is some inconsistency with the behaviour of the API itself.  I am not sure at this point what the best method of handling these errors is given that re-attempts of the failing requests continue to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If the errors are repeatable, I don't think they are random.

Please check that the tokens have not been revoked.

Comment: The errors are only occur by immediately recycling the curl request.  They are not repeatable (attempting to recreate them will return passing results).  They immediately follow and precede successful requests to the same user (within seconds), so the tokens are definitely not revoked.

Comment: Hey Ali, any movement on this? We're still fighting these random problems with Drive.

Comment: @EricWarnke Need more information please. Are the errors random, or repeatable?

Comment: @AliAfshar The errors are non-repeatable and occur on random API calls at random intervals.